# Is this simple concept against spam valid? (Optimization required?)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bots, spam

**Introduction**

We were dealing with some spam-issue in an earlier project we did and prevent any spam bots with the following simple concept. I now want to implement this into a way larger project. Before I do this I wish to optimize it that this works in multiple forms on the same page, but I'm not getting the trick yet or I'm not sure if its worth rebuild this into a more complex version if its useless.

*For clarification: I don't want to deal with CAPTCHA or similar things. Just do a native solution.*

**Concept**

If the user focus any `input` field of the form an AJAX-Query will be sent where a random hash-tag will be generated and stored into a `$_SESSION` variable. This hash will be also written into a hidden input-field called `spamKey` (for example).

After the user submit the form I check if the `$_SESSION["spamKey"]` variable is equal to the `$_POST["spamKey"]` variable so I decide to process the query or not.

**The code**

*Simple form*

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formOne">

    <label for='input_eins'>Name</label>
        <input type='text' id='input_eins' name='name' />
    <label for='input_user'>E-Mail</label>
        <input type='text' id='input_user' name='user' />
    <label for='ta_text'>Comment</label>
        <textarea name='text'></textarea>
    <label for='input_spamKey'>spamKey</label>
        <input type='text' id='input_spamKey' name='spamKey' />
    <input type='submit' value='Senden'>
</form>
```

*script.js (using jQuery)*

```
var spamKey = false;
$("#formOne > input").focus(function() {
         if(spamKey == false) {
        dataString = "action=getSpamKey";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'asyncresponse.php',
            data: dataString,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#input_spamKey").val(data);
                if(data != "") {
                    spamKey = true;
                }
              }
        });
    }
});
```

*asyncresponse.php (Info: The POST-Variables are sanitized)*

```
if($_POST["action"] == "getSpamKey") {
    $spamKey = md5(time().microtime());
    $_SESSION["spamKey"] = $spamKey;
    echo $spamKey;
}
```

*check routine in PHP*

```
($_SESSION["spamKey"] == $_POST["spamKey"] && !empty($_SESSION["spamKey"]))
```

**Okay - whats my question?**

Which steps you would suggest me to protect multiple forms? And probably a basic question - is this a valid solution to deal with the spam issue?

Thanks for your help in advance.

A simple demo you can find here: 
http://godesign.ch/labor/antispam/index.php

Comment: If it catches on, and/or your site is popular enough, the spammers will adapt. Not all of them at once, but they will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captcha used to be an effective method of preventing spam.  It is now broken because it was widely implemented, creating an economic incentive to break it (google "captcha broken").

I have seen this method be effective in projects.  You risk that someone, at some point, will be motivated to break it.  Correctly implemented, I believe it provides reasonable protection against spam at this point in time.

Comment: I agree. It will stop casual spammers and auto-post scripts. What it will not stop is a scripted headless browser.

Comment: @Eric J. - Thanks for your answer, it was interesting to read that captcha is broken. So it seems to be worth using this as a starting point.

Comment: @Diodeus - is there a way to detect those browsers? Do they have any identification? Probably they fill out the forms too quickly so I could measure the time?

Comment: Of course these browsers will spoof their user agents. The more valuable the target, the more sophisticated the attack. Simply leaving the ACTION field blank on your form and setting it via JS on the first keystroke is just as good as your proposal.

Comment: @godesign A spammer can represent itself as any browser fairly easily and most browsers offer the ability to misrepresent themselves thanks to an early/mid 00's practice of building websites for IE only.  You can identify browsers but you still can't trust them if they appear to be correct.  As the old saying goes: The most secure system is one that no one could use. Oddly, user agent detection is becoming popular again for mobile detection.  It's still as hairy as it was back-when.

Comment: @jmbertucci: When I looked over the analysis of millions of query strings a few years back, there were plenty of things like `Jim's iPhone`.